# Android MyLocationOverlay vs LocationManager/LocationListener

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android application that shows the user his/her current location (using MyLocationOverlay), and I am also using a LocationManager/LocationListener to get the user's location every 15 seconds, which is then used to query a web service and in return I plot points using an ItemizedOverlay.

This is all working with no problems.

Should I be using BOTH MyLocationOverlay as well as LocationManager/LocationListener, however?  It seems redundant.  What would you do?  From what I can see, MyLocationOverlay uses the LocationManager in the background to constantly receive location updates, anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MyLocationOverlay does a little more such as adding the overlay to the map, showing the error radius and making it cool and blinky!  There is nothing wrong with using it in conjunction with getting your own updates.  In my app I decided not to use it because I wanted to change the way that it looked so that it was more like what you see in the Maps app where the MyLocationOverlay is an arrow that shows what direction you're facing.  It's really a matter of preference.

Comment: This is a helpful answer, I think that I am indeed going to use both.  The only thing that I have to fiddle around with, it seems, is making sure the location of my markers is the same as the MyLocation location (as I'm finding that the LocationManager and the MyLocation will sometimes return different locations)...